# How do different input image sizes/resolutions affect the output quality of semantic image segmentation networks?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, image-segmentation

While trying to perform image segmentation on images from one dataset ([KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php)) with a deep learning network trained on another dataset ([Cityscapes](https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/)) I realized that there is a big difference in subjectively perceived quality of the output (and probably also when benchmarking the (m)IoU).

This raised my question, if and how size/resolution of an input image affects the output from a network for semantic image segmentation which has been trained on images with different size or resolution than the input image.

I attached two images and their corresponding output images from this network: https://github.com/hellochick/PSPNet-tensorflow (using provided weights).

The first image is from the CityScapes dataset (test set) with a width and height of (2048,1024). The network has been trained with training and validation images from this dataset.

[CityScapes original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6xS0.jpg)

[CityScapes output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OVyj.png)

The second image is from the KITTI dataset with a width and height of (1242,375):

[KITTI original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX9Ub.jpg)

[KITTI output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljwNu.png)

As one can see, the shapes in the first segmented image are clearly defined while in the second one a detailed separation of objects is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Neural networks in general are fairly robust to variations in scale, but they certainly aren't perfect. Although I don't have references available off the top of my head there have been a number of papers that show that scale does indeed affect accuracy.

In fact training your network with a dataset with images at varying scales is almost certainly going to improve it.

Also, many of the image segmentation networks used today explicitly build constructs into the network to improve this at the level of the network architecture.

Since you probably don't know exactly how these networks were trained I would suggest that you resize your images to match the approximate shape that the network you are using was trained on. Resizing an image using normal image resize functions is quite a normal preprocessing step.

Since the images you are referencing there are large I'm also going to say that whatever data input pipeline you're feeding them through is already resizing the images on your behalf. Most neural networks of this type are trained on images of around 256x256. The input image is cropped and centered as necessary before training or prediction. Processing very large images like that is extremely compute-intensive and hasn't been found to improve the accuracy much.